# Add event listener to chrome extension button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, onclicklistener, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am new to chrome extension development, and I understand that this question is simple but I couldn't find it online. I was wondering how I could add a listener and hide or show a certain div on chrome extension button press. This is my current code in manifest.js for background where I am trying to connect chrome extension click (which is not working) to content.js.

```
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

and this is my background.js file...

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0" });
    //above code used for testing but never gets executed for some reason when I try to click chrome extension button
});
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!!!

Comment: Use messaging. See this for working example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296716/1225070

Comment: @Aefits you sent me an answer for manifest 2. I tried converting ```background.scripts to background.service_worker``` but the message to background.js never gets sent.

Comment: In MV3 it's `action`, not `browserAction`. You also need `"action":{}` in manifest.json

Comment: Got it! Thank you didn't see that answer before.